# scala: abstract methods in traits

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, traits

I create trait with one abstract method. Then I create a class that uses this trait. This class contains concrete overridden method. So this code works just fine

```
  trait Logged {
    def log(msg: String)
  }

  class A extends Logged{
    def log(msg: String) {
      println(msg)
    }
    def a(msg: String) {
      log(msg)
    }
  }

  val a = new A
  a.log("jopa")
```

But when I create a trait chain things get messy:

```
  trait Logged {
    def log(msg: String)
  }

  trait TimestampLogger extends Logged {
    abstract override def log(msg: String) {
      super.log("huy: " + msg)
    }
  }

  class A extends Logged with TimestampLogger {
    def log(msg: String) {
      println(msg)
    }
    def a(msg: String) {
      log(msg)
    }
  }

  val a = new A
  a.log("jopa")
```

This code doesn't work neither with `overridden` log method modifier, nor with anything I tried.
What is the problem?

Comment: `super.log` in `TimestampLogger` makes no sense. It's not implemented.

Comment: @LimbSoup so how can I use the log hierarchy? How can I use that log method?

Comment: Don't you want a default (but not abstract) definition in Logged? Then you can override it in subclasses.

Comment: @LimbSoup since your comment has an approval rating, I must respond that the intention of the code is obvious, that the timestamper decorates the log method. It's fair to say abstract override is tricky.

Comment: The answer here wrongly suggests that the mix-in is not statically determined, but anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852101/what-are-stackable-modifications

Answer (score 1):

Use stackable traits this way:

http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.5

The concrete implementation must be in a parent in linearization order.

```
new A with TimestampLogger
```

i.e.,

```
trait Logged {
    def log(msg: String)
}

trait TimestampLogger extends Logged {
    abstract override def log(msg: String) {
        super.log("huy: " + msg)
    }
}

class A extends Logged {
    def log(msg: String) {
        println(msg)
    }
    def a(msg: String) {
        log(msg)
    }
}

object Test extends App {
    val a = new A with TimestampLogger
    a.log("jopa")
}
```

or similar.